# Start a service from a webapp with administrator privileges passing by a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, admin

I'm working on a monitoring app that is running on a vm and I want my colleagues to be able to use it without connecting on the vm. It works fine but I have one problem.

One of my goals is to start/stop services using a batch file or a cmd file (using Class Runtime in my back). The problem is that I need the administrator privileges to do that. All the methods I found (as Runas or some batch files) only works if the user is on the vm and enter the password or click on the "do you want to run this application as administrator" pop up. I would like to not use the task scheduler to always start cmd as an admin. I already know you can use softwares as "Sanur" but I prefer not to.

The only way to make it works is to start the app as an admin and it works fine (I'm using the "net start/stop" command). But I would like to let everyone start this app (in case I'm not here).
It's not a problem to write the login/password in the file.

Is there a way to do so?

The vm runs on Windows 7.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be Administrator to start and stop a service, you just need the privilege. With Windows 7 Professional you can do this through the built-in group policy editor.

With Windows 7 Home, there is not policy editor.

I use a tool called [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/) to do this, e.g:

```
setacl -on "service-name" -ot srv -actn ace -ace "n:betrand;p:start_stop"
```

Where `"service-name"` is the name of the service, and `betrand` is the user which you want to allow to start and stop the service.

A complete list of options is available on the website:

- https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/

Another option is the [SubInACL](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=23418) tool directly from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as you say I can't use the build-in group policy editor. In the end, I will have to use an external tool to achieve my goals, wouldn't I? I should be more specific in my question, but I have no rights to import tools or softwares (That's why I'm trying to only use a batch file). I really appreciate your answer, thank you.

Comment: @Y.Bertrand: `setacl.exe` requires not installation. You just download it, run it and assign the privileges.

Comment: `@a_horse_with_no_name` As I previously said, I haven't the rights to use any tools. I'm working on a closed network and I can't put any new tools. It's a really strict conditions of ours. That's why I would like to use only a script I can write. But thank you for the tips.

Comment: Granting the necessary privileges is the **only** alternative you have, if you don't want to make everybody administrator. You need to find some way of granting them. Either through the group policy or by using some other tool. I don't see any other option. If this is so important, then you need to ask whoever is in charge of the administrator to either grant those privileges or allow the use of a tool for this (SubInACL is provided if non Microsoft tools are completely out of question)

Comment: `@a_horse_with_no_name@` Ok, if it's the only way, I will let this as it is or ask my superior. I will close my question, thank you a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: You don't need an external tool.  You can set the permissions with `sc`, or using the Windows API, whatever suits you.  Generally you would do this at the same time and using the same method that you use install the service.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: hmm, are you sure you can grant the privilege to start and stop a service to a _user_ through `sc`? As far as I know, `sc` can only change the privileges the _service_ has, not those of a user

Comment: Being able to start or stop a service isn't a privilege, it's a permission, determined by the ACL on the service in question.  The `sc sdset` command can change the ACL, same as the `SetACL` tool, though it uses a different syntax.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: very interesting. Why don't you add an answer with an example? That sounds like a better solution then my answer.