# Why can I pass credentials to a regular user but not a local administrator?

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation

So basically I've been working forever on a PS remote self help script that originally was thought to be simple: Restart the spooler service, clear the queue, and print a test page on the default printer. Getting there however hasn't been so easy, due to security issues. After some hours, I was able to get my local user test account to accept the credentials of my domain administrator. I thought all was well, until I tried to replicate it on a local administrator's account, in which event access was denied. This is sort of important, because the majority of the accounts we will be deploying the script on **are** local admins. I suspect it may be a UAC issue, but I have no idea what I should do to work around the problem. Here's what I'm working with currently:

```
$v = [bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544") 
If ($v = "False") 
{
$password = "ElPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force 
$username = "Domainname\Username"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
invoke-command {Stop-Service spooler} -comp $env:ComputerName -cred $credential
Remove-Item C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\* -Force
invoke-command {Start-Service spooler} -comp $env:ComputerName -cred $credential
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" 
$PrintTestPage = $printer.PrintTestPage() } Else 
{ Stop-Service spooler 
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" 
Start-Service spooler
$PrintTestPage = $printer.PrintTestPage() }
```

The first thing this does is check if the current PS session is being run as admin; seeing as the users don't actually see the PowerShell window or script, and we recently started using the RMM tool, I'm still trying to figure out under what conditions the tool runs PS elevated - the documentation says that it runs with the credentials of the logged in user, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as an hour with their support team told me that the reason the script wasn't doing it's job on *any* admin accounts was because it wasn't being elevated. Anyways, after the check, it either passes credentials for the commands or it doesn't. This script seems to handle every scenario but that of a **local admin** account running PS non elevated. In that event, it simply denies me access where the exact same creds give me access on a regular user account.  I'm not sure how to even approach this problem, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What problem, exactly, are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can pass credentials to a local administrator, without getting an "access denied" error when executing the commands.

Comment: That is, if it's possible without fully disabling UAC...

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Why do you need to do that? Tell the problem, not your attempted solution.

Comment: Sorry, must have misinterpreted your Q. I need to do that in order to restart the printer spooler service, and to print a test page to the default printer via remote script on local admin accounts.  Clearing the queue folder can be done without elevation.

Comment: Again: Why do you need to do this? What problem are you solving?

Comment: It's a self-help tool for an end user, so I'm not really solving anything. It's more of a contingency script for when a printer malfunctions, so time can be saved on both ends.

Comment: That being said, I could easily see the need to apply credentials to a local admin account being present in a variety of other situations. So, I thought this would be a good question to ask. If it's not possible, at least people will know so.

Comment: If you need for end users to be able to restart the spooler, then set the the privilege for the spooler service so the Users group can stop and start it. For example: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250425/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250425/).